# Bing Webmaster API responding Error 400 ThrottleUser

Tags: bing-webmaster-tools

As the subject line states, all API calls for the past 6 days have resulted in Error 400 ThrottleUser responses. Tried a new api key; pox, json and service connections.

Is this happening to everyone? Does anyone know how to tell them it is not working?

Comment: All Bing Webmaster API calls still return: {"ErrorCode":4,"Message":"ERROR!!! ThrottleUser"}
How do we let Microsoft know?

Answer (score -1):

Support can be requested here: https://www.bing.com/webmaster/support

as suggested here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f24edc35-5aab-445a-91b8-73a1982019d7/webmaster-api?forum=whatforum

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. That support service is for the Webmaster Tools only. They told me they do not support the API. They pointed kme to a generic Microsoft Support page that does not offer any specific support for  the Bing Webmaster API...or anything vaguely similar.  I am pleading with them to look into it anyways...